# Gradle Cannot change strategy of configuration ':optional' after it has been resolved.

Tags: gradle, jackson, gradlew, fasterxml

I am trying to force the version of com.fasterxml.jackson.core, however, when I configured like below, it won't allow me to force the version of depedencies and throw me error.

build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
       dependencies {
        testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVer"
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$mockitoVer"
        compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVer"

        // logging
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVer"
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:$slf4jVer"
        compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVer"
        compile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4jVer"
        compile "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:$slf4jVer"

        compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:$logbackVer"
        compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVer"
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVer"
            force "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVer"
            force "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVer"
            force "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:$jacksonVer"
            force "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:$jacksonVer"
            force "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider:$jacksonVer"

            cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
Cannot change strategy of configuration ':optional' after it has been resolved.
```

Any idea?